# how to restore browser standered features while loading pages into div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

the problem is that my website consists of only one page which contain a side menu and a div while all other pages are loaded in it, the problem is all of the browser slandered features(back, refresh, bookmark) are all gone. so my question is there a way to restore browser features while loading pages into div, or i should use another way to load pages in the main page?.

main page:

```
<div id="nav" class="mmenu">
            <ul id="nav_ul" class="float_left">
                <li><a class="upper" id="1" target="collabsoft" href= "profilePage.php?property_variable=mine">My Profile</a></li>
                <li><a id="2" class="menu-message"
                       href= "viewMessages.php">Messages<label id="num_msg">(<?php echo $count; ?>)</label></a></li>
                <li><a id="3" class="menu-conference"  target="collabsoft" href= "userHomepage.php">My Conferences</a></li>
                <li><a id="4" class="menu-conference2"  target="collabsoft" href= "availableConferences2.php">Conferences</a></li>
                <li><a id="5" class="menu-request"
                       href= "incomingRequests.php">Requests<label id="num_requests">(<?php echo $total ?>)</label></a></li>
                <li><a id="6" class="menu-news"
                       target="collabsoft" href= "viewNews.php" >News</a></li>
                <li><a class="lower" id="7" target="collabsoft" href= "generalOptions.php" >Options</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <table id="collabsoft_table" class="no_border">
            <tr>
                <td id="collabsoft_td" class="no_border">
                    <div scrolling="no" id="collabsoft" name="collabsoft" class="collabsoft"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "gone"? They're still there, but when you refresh the pages it goes back to your home/initial page?

Comment: You could use hashes. So a link could navigate from `http://site.com/` to `http://site.com/#page2`

Comment: I assume you want to have a mechanism with which you can those features on your website namely... refresh,back etc?

Comment: What browser are you using? Is your website using HTML frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have different URLs for different resources, otherwise the browser won't keep/update its history and the server would serve the same page.

- You should use hash links (the part after the "#" char in the URL)
- Another option is to use HTML5's History API, which could be used to "push" a fake URL

Let's focus on the first option (hash URLs), mainly because of browser support.

Also, you did not specify if you're using any JavaScript framework, I'm going to assume you're using jQuery (because of its popularity).

Look into [jQuery History](https://github.com/balupton/jquery-history/)

Let me explain how it works:

When you create a link, instead of binding to its "click" event, give it a hash string, for example:

```
<a href="#about" title="About me">About</a>
```

When the link is clicked, the browser won't reload the page.

Then, use the jQuery History plugin to bind to that history change, for example:

```
$.History.bind('/about',function(state){
    // Load resource using AJAX, update the "main" div, etc.
});
```